# communicating the idea of stationary distribution and ergodic theorem

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I will teach the Markov chain for the first time to someone who has not much background in it, and I have little, but I am trying to read and understand intuitively to convey the idea in layman's terms.

Consider an irreducible, positive recurrent Markov chain with $3$ states with unique stationary probability distribution $\pi$ such that $\pi(1)=\frac{1}{2}=\pi_1, \pi(2)=\frac{1}{3}=\pi_2, \pi(3)=\frac{1}{6}=\pi_3$. Let $v_i(n)$ denote the number of visits of state $i$ before time $n$, and a well-known theorem says the following:

$$\mathbb P\left[\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{v_i(n)}{n}\to\pi_i\right]=1.$$

1. Can I say to the target audience that, by a stationary probability distribution, they can think that if they watch the evolution of the Markov chain for a long-time let's say for $10$ ( or should I say $100$) hours, considering discrete time step as minutes. They will see $\frac{1}{2}\times 10$ hours they will see the chain is visiting state $1$, $\frac{1}{3}\times 10$ hours in-state $2$ and $\frac{1}{6}\times 10$ hours in-state $3$. Is that the correct way to convey the intuition behind stationary probability distribution? They may ask in which order of hours they will see this event.
2. And, the above limit precisely conveys the fact I just said in point $1$, with probability $1$.

Please let me know and suggest if this can be made far easier to convey.

3. Another thing: if $f:\{1,2,3\}\to \mathbb R$ is any bounded function let say $f(x)=e^x$, ergodic theorem says $$\mathbb P\left[\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}f(X_k)\to\sum\limits_{i\in\{1,2,3\}}f(i)\pi_i\right]=1.$$

I am not sure, what is the intuition to bring $f$ here and how can I convey the usefulness of this result to a general audience without much background to the Markov chain.

Thank you.

Comment: Nitpicking perhaps: but in this example $\pi$ is not a "probability" distribution.

Comment: Thanks edited the $\pi$.

Comment: Intuitively this is the law of large numbers for dependent random variables. Bremauld has a chapter on this in his book.

Comment: Your description of stationary distribution sounds more like the description of a limiting distribution. These two concepts should be introduced seperately, and then you can introduce the students to the important fact, that the limiting distribution coincides with the unique stationary distribution in the case of irreducible aperiodic markov chains on a finite state space.

Comment: About the ergodic theorem it is important to state the importance of the indicator function $f(x)=1(x=i)$, since
$$\frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1(X_k=i) = \frac{v_i(n)}{n},$$
hence you could use it to prove this special case of the theorem or use this special case as a motivation for the general theorem.

Comment: I read some posts on limiting distribution and stationary distribution...honestly I am confused now... haha..could you be kind enough to write some main points to keep in mind very shortly. Thank you.

Comment: A stationary distribution is a distribution $\pi$ such that, if $X_0 \sim \pi$, then the marginal distribution of $X_{1}$ is also $\pi$. By induction this gives that $X_k \sim \pi$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. In other words, if the initial distribution is stationary, then the marginal distribution does not change with time. This is the essence of the word "stationary", something which does not change. Written in terms of the transition matrix $P$, we then get that $\pi$ is stationary if and only if 
$$\pi = \pi P.$$

Comment: A limiting distribution is a distribution $\pi$, such that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n = j \: | \: X_0 = i) = \pi_j$$
for all $i$ and $j$. The distribution of $X_n$ is given by $ \pi_0P^n$, where $\pi_0$ is the initial distribution. This means that the limiting distribution (when it exists) is a distribution $\pi$, such that
$$\pi = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \pi_0 P^n$$
for all initial distributions $\pi_0$. Note, that
$$\pi =  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \pi_0 P^{n+1} = \pi P,$$
such that the limiting distribution is stationary.

Comment: Thank you, do you know a book (other than Meyn and Tweedy) which discuss in a coherent manner of Markov chain on uncountable state-space?